# Prefix/Group Symfony Console Commands of an dependency

Tags: symfony, symfony-console

With symfony console commands you can prefix/group each one by putting in the setName("group:command"), and this is great.

```
myown
  myown:cool
  myown:foo
  myown:bar
```

But the problem is that some external dependencies dont use this format. Ex: Phinx Migrations.

Since I'm importing an dependency that has a console command called `migrate`, I dont want for it to show without prefix/group. Not just because I might have another command called `migrate` or just for readability. I don't event know if we have 2 with same command name which one will show (need to check).

My question is: Is there any away for me to force a group commands from an external depencency to be inside an prefix/group?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that, I wouldn't recommend but that would be the approach:

- Create a compiler Pass which removes the definitions of the Commands you don't like
- Register again all those commands while setting the names you like

If you need information on compiler passes:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/compilation.html#components-di-compiler-pass

Maybe there's an easier way which I'm not aware, but for now that's my answer to you, I can't post all the code because that would be a lot of code and if you do it maybe you can update with the solution.

Good luck